# how to select value from group by using linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Can anyone help me to write the equivalent sql to linq in C#

```
select 
COUNT(ot.UserId) as orderCount, SUM(ot.TotalAmount) as TotalAmount,
MAX(u.UserName) as UserName, MAX(c.name) as ClientName
from OrderTemplate ot
join User u
on u.userid = ot.UserId
join Client c
on u.ClientID = c.clientid
group by ot.UserId
```

What I have done is,

```
from ot in dbContext.OrderTemplates
join user in dbContext.Users on ot.UserId equals user.UserID
join client in dbContext.Clients on user.ClientID equals client.ClientID
group ot by ot.UserId into g
select new 
{ 
    //UserName = need to pick this from user table
    //ClientName = need to pick this from client table
    OrderCount = g.Count(),
    TotalAmount = g.Sum(x=> x.TotalAmount)
};
```

I can't select the value which according to sql.

Comment: What are the values of `UserName`? What does `Max(u.Username)` actually mean? are those the same user names? are some of the values `null` and then you do `max` to get the one that isnt?

Comment: Yes the username will be same for each of group , so i just need to pick any one.

Comment: Also in your sql you are gouping by the `UserId` but in the linq by the `OrderId`

Answer (score 2):

So if the usernames and client names are the same (and actaully each order has one client and one user) better group by multiple keys:

```
from ot in dbContext.OrderTemplates
join u in dbContext.Users on ot.UserId equals u.UserID
join c in dbContext.Clients on u.ClientID equals c.ClientID
group ot by new { ot.UserId, u.UserName, c.ClientName } into g
select new 
{ 
    UserName = g.Key.UserName,
    ClientName = g.Key.ClientName,
    OrderCount = g.Count(),
    TotalAmount = g.Sum(x=> x.TotalAmount)
};
```

If they are not, or if you want exactly like your sql then instead of a key with multiple properties when instantiating the anonymous object:

```
Username = g.Max(item => item.UserName) // will just use string comparison to select the "max"
```